# Scala: How do I use the repository sistanlp/processors?

Tags: java, git, scala, stanford-nlp, processors

I've been having a lot of problems with trying to use the following repository: https://github.com/sistanlp/processors

I already have Scala and Java installed. I got Stanford CoreNLP but I'm not sure if I set it up correctly.

I ran 'sbt compile' and 'sbt assembly' with the build.sbt file in the 'processors' files that I got from the repository mentioned above. It seemed to work, though I got some warnings.

I moved all the .jar files I could find into a classes folder within a target folder.

I followed the instructions from here: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/joint-compilation-of-scala-and-java-sources to compile the example java code in the sistanlp/processors repository (the last code example in the readme), I entered the following:

```
javac -d /home/mra235/processors-master/processors-master/target/scala-2.11/classes       -classpath $SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar:/home/mra235/processors-master/processors-master/target/scala-2.11/classes        src/main/java/*.java
```

But I got errors, in particular the following error:

```
warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature'
```

I am out of ideas ... I probably set up something incorrectly, such as the processors repository or the Standford CoreNLP, but then I don't know what I did wrong.